# SQL || How to Recursively Look for a term(s) in long text, and returning the word n before and after

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have various terms e.g

```
in
et
```

I have many docs with long strings of text e.g

```
("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
```

Using SQL Server (I can't build Full Text Index), can I get the word before and after a given word (or multiple terms), everywhere it appears in the text.

What I hope to end up with:

```
| File id | term| Phrase                     |
|---------|-----|----------------------------|
| 1       | in  | dolor in reprehenderit     | 
| 1       | in  | reprehenderit in voluptate |
| 1       | in  | sunt in culpa              |
| 1       | et  |labore et dolore            |
| 2       | in  | sunt in culpa              |
```

Thanks, happy to be told this is crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Try this using String_Split, RowNumber & Lead & Lag

**Setup**

```
Create Table Terms
(
    Id Int Identity,
    Term varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO Terms(Term)
Values ('in'), ('et')
```

Query

```
DECLARE @str varchar(max) =
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod ' + 
'tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, ' +
'quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ' +
'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat ' +
'nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia ' +
'deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';


with words as 
(
    select value word, 
           Row_Number() over (order by (select 0)) rowN from String_Split(@str, ' ')
),
Phrases AS
(
    select  rowN, 
            word, 
            LAG(word, 1) OVER (ORDER BY rowN) as PrevVal, 
            Lead(word, 1) Over (Order by RowN) NextVal
    FROM words
)
SELECT Term, PrevVal + ' ' + word + ' ' + NextVal As Phrase 
FROM Phrases
INNER JOIN Terms
    ON Phrases.word = Terms.Term
```

**Results**

```
Term    Phrase
-----   ---------------------
et      labore et dolore
in      dolor in reprehenderit
in      reprehenderit in voluptate
in      sunt in culpa
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, this works for 1 word terms, how would this be adapted if there was a multi-word term? e.g if i was looking for 'dolor in'? Would that be possible?